# Nodejs return data after get request inside a post request

Tags: node.js, express, request, node-request

i'm trying to pass get request answer to the post request but can't, can someone help me please?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

http.listen(9999, function() {
  console.log('listening...');
});

app.post('/bot',function(req,res){
  var apiurl = 'https://apiURI'
  request(apiurl, function(error,response,body){
    res.send(body)
  })
}
```

when i receive the api answer should send to client who make the post request with res.send

```
error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is actually in code that you haven't included. This most often happens to me if I try to do a `res.send` twice somewhere along my middleware pipeline. It could be as simple as there being a `res.send` somewhere after that request call.

Comment: Yes, you'r right there is some code that i don't include here, this is the isolated code that doesn't work but there is no other res.send instruction before this, i found it at end the of my original code, this line 'res.end()' was giving me the error, thanks for your time @JeremyPridemore, regards!

Comment: Not to be stubborn, but the problem isn't in your listed code. To prove this, I change your apiurl to `'http://google.com'` and actually ran this program locally and it works fine. Some of the times I've hit this error, I had a `res.send()` in an `if` statement and one outside of it, with no`return` in the if statement. So they both ran. Either way, we can't help yet because the actual problem isn't in the code you posted from what I can tell.

Comment: don't worry @JeremyPridemore , as i mention, the problem is solved, res.end() method fires the mentioned error. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I misread. Good job fixing it! Do you mind posting your own answer? There's nothing worse than stumbling over an old question that is relevant to you and solved by the poster with no explanation. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Error solved, deleting the end() method outside the get request due to it's a async request (my mistake)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

http.listen(9999, function() {
  console.log('listening...');
});

app.post('/bot',function(req,res){
  var apiurl = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=72cc6a313e2b4fb3af09e4593ee06fbc'
  request(apiurl, function(error,response,body){
    res.send(body)
  })
  //res.end()
})
```

Comment: how about a POST ? this is GET ?